# How to efficiently read and edit long expressions

Tags: sourcecode

I can get a bit overwhelmed trying to find which frac or h symbol corresponds to the output of a complex expression.

An easy way is to copy paste into lyx and edit there as you can edit the output directly by clicking on the right symbol but that can cause context switches and might lead to using the mouse which might break the flow and slow down the writing process.

Comment: You can utilize the synctex function to accomplish backward and forward jump.

Comment: @Stephen I am using okular and i checked and I think it only detects the line of the equation. Do you have a pdf viewer that is able to detect the latex command that corresponds to a specific symbol in a formula ?

Comment: I think it's enough to jump to the corresponding line provided that every line isn't very long (no more than 60 characters per line).